C# LINQ SUM takes longer than expected
I currently testing for a MVC application and found that one of page seems to take longer.
By measuring times for each execution of lines by lines, I discovered that one of LINQ line takes more than 5 seconds. I know that the query itself is not that complicated but I have few hundreds or thousands rows in the Database.
grandTotal = items.Sum(x => x.InvoiceDetails.Sum(s => s.BillingItem.TotalAmount)) ?? 0;
By any way, is it possible to get this operation execute faster ? I look up another thread saying going through forloop is actually faster than LINQ. But since item is type of IQueryable, I assumed this was the only way to get the sum out of my knowledge.

Can you run a profiler to see the SQL commands that are executed for this line of code? If the performance can be improved by an index then these queries will help us find it.

It's also not clear if the sum is actually happening in SQL or in-memory, or if the time is spent just fetching the data then doing the sum. We'd need to see how items is populated to give more concrete advice

And "for loop is faster than linq" is true only in the sense of in-memory calculations where linq adds a very slight overhead over a raw loop. It will not make the sum materially faster just by itself.

@BartMcEndree I do not have Database Profiler supported for my project.

@DStanley items is defined as followed : var items = db.Invoices.Where(x => !x.VoidOn.HasValue).AsQueryable(); and  I am assuming that I is happening in SQL

Does this answer your question? Sum nested values with Linq

Regarding the Sum nested values with Linq question linked above: The initial question is different, but I believe the two general query forms (query syntax and method syntax) in the accepted answer may help. Bottom line - follow the joins down to the values and perform a single sum.  The (int?) or (OtherType?) casting may not be needed in your case.

You could try flipping the query db.BillingItem.Where(b => !b.InvoiceDetails.Invoice.VoidOn.HasValue).Sum(b => b.TotalAmount). But you'll need to examine the sql and query plan to know for sure. Do you really need to sum the total amount of all invoices for all time?

What is items where does that come from?

A poor implementation for your use of Sum here is if the query has to be done as a single transaction at a time. D Stanley asks about this in his comment to your question. Ideally you want the calculation to happen in your database if it's got the CPU to handle it as that will minimize how much data that needs to be transmitted. Otherwise you want to do a single query that pulls the relevant rows and then sum them locally.
What you probably have happening is something like:
query first bill total value from server
add total to sum
query second bill total value from server
add total to sum
etc.

Each of these is a relatively slow data connection that we want to avoid. So, 2 solutions:

Add an InvoiceSum stored procedure to your database that you can call. I'm assuming that's not an option, but will probably be the fastest for you if it is. (Along these lines you could also send a request to your database that will do the sum, but that loses the flexibility of a generic LINQ statement.)
Gather all of your rows as a single query. You may not be able to do this with the library you are using. LINQ, more or less by definition, uses Enumerable which only looks at a single element at a time.


A note on for loop vs LINQ. LINQ has a little more overhead than for loops, but especially for larger loops the difference is marginal. If you are making lots of small queries a for loop can be better as it will not add to your garbage collector pressure. But occasional LINQ statements will be very affordable. Performance checks are always a good idea to see if it's actually a problem. Certainly you may do quite well by just removing your nested Sum statement and replacing it with a for loop.

items.SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceDetails).Sum(s => s.BillingItem.TotalAmount) might take care of the joins for you

I did think about adding in something like that. SelectMany is certainly more likely to conduct a single transaction given that there is an implicit expectation that it will return more than 1 row, but so would Sum, hence why I didn't add it in my answer. It's certainly an excellent observation for any reader though.

I believe you need to first drill down through the joins and then apply a single .Sum() calculation at the end.
Try one of the following:
grandTotal = (from item in items
             from invoiceDetail in item.InvoiceDetails
             select invoiceDetail.BillingItem.TotalAmount)
             .Sum() ?? 0;

grandTotal = items
    .SelectMany(item => item.InvoiceDetails)
    .Sum(invoiceDetail => invoiceDetail.BillingItem.TotalAmount)
    ?? 0;

The first uses query syntax, while the second uses method syntax to define what I believe to be identical operations.
